# Angular Modal Cannot Resolve From Factory

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have an AngularJS factory which I am attempting to use to create modals. However, when I attempt to use the `resolve` method in the `$modal` my modal instance controller gets an unresolved provider.

Here is how I am calling my factory from my controller:

```
var modalOptions = {
    template: 'app/common/modalwindow.html',
    data: data
};

modalFactory.openModal(modalOptions);
```

My modal factory is simple for now, all it has is a single open modal method:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

var factoryId = 'modalFactory';
angular.module('app').factory(factoryId, ['$modal', modalFactory]);

function modalFactory($modal) {
    var factory = {
        openModal: openModal
    }

    return factory;

    function openModal(data) {
        $modal.open({
            templateUrl: data.template,
            controller: 'modalInstanceCtrl',
            resolve: {
                modalData: function () {
                    return data.data;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
})();
```

However, when my `modalInstanceCtrl` is called it throws an error. Here is my `modalInstanceCtrl`

```
(function () {
'use strict';

var controllerId = 'modalInstanceCtrl';
angular.module('app').controller(controllerId, ['common', 'modalData', modalInstanceCtrl]);

function modalInstanceCtrl(common, modalData) {
    var getLogFn = common.logger.getLogFn;
    var log = getLogFn(controllerId);
    log(modalData);

};
})();
```

The error it throws is:

> Unknown provider: modalDataProvider <- modalData <- modalInstanceCtrl

I thought the `resolve` in the `$modal` would handle this injection. Am I assuming wrong here?